# cx_Oracle not found in RDP

Tags: django, cx-oracle

I am trying to run the django in remote server where Internet access is not avaiable, I have copied the libaries/pacakages from my local to remote server and tried to run it and packages were accepted but cx_Oracle it is module not installed.I have already set the client libary path in environmental path.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\HC_REST\HC_REST> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader 
Exception in thread django-main-thread: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 52, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle as Database 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run     
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load 
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 141, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 231, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sysadm01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading cx_Oracle module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading cx_Oracle module: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

Comment: The error suggests you don't have cx_Oracle installed! What makes you think that it is? You can also try with the latest version (python-oracledb) which has a thin mode which doesn't require Oracle Client libraries.